# find values of second array based off of index of first array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Lets say I have the following two arrays, with a `keyValue` object as well.

```
int[] values = {3, 1, 1, 2, 3};
int[] keys   = {6, 5, 5, 6, 9};
int   keyValue = 7;
```

I am trying to find the greatest `value` for a `key` that is less than the `keyValue`. In the example above, we are looking for 7. The correct answer in this case would be 3, since the greatest `key <= 7` is 6. The indexes of 6 in `keys` are 0 and 3. So I would look at `value[0]` and `value[3]` and find that the largest would be `value[0] = 3`.

If I re-sort the `keys` I would need to resort the values to make sure the indexes matched up, so I would like to keep both lists the same.

I could use a brute force algorithm and do something like this

```
int foundValue = 0;
int foundKey = 0;
Foreach ( int x = 0; x < keys.length; x++ ){
    if ( keys[x] <= keyValue && keys[x] >= foundKey) {
      foundKey = keys[x];
      if(values[x] > foundValue){
         foundValue = values[x];
      }
   }
}
```

which works but isn't all that elegant. The issue is that I actually need to sum the `values[x]` based on a changing `keyValue`, and can't include repetition. For example

```
keyValue = 7    :    foundValue = 3
keyValue = 7    :    foundValue = 2   //because value[0] was already used
keyValue = 5    :    foundValue = 1   
keyValue = 10   :    foundValue = 3
keyValue = 7    :    foundValue = 1   //because all the 6 and one 5 value are used
```

Is there a better way than brute force to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore the "elegance" requirement for the moment, and deal with the real issue first, which is that you

> need to sum the `values[x]` based on a changing `keyValue`, and can't
>   include repetition.

To prevent the reuse of a value, you should add a `used[]` array as shown below. The following algorithm also allows a changing `keyValue` by the addition of a `while` loop:

```
int[] values = {3, 1, 1, 2, 3};
int[] keys   = {6, 5, 5, 6, 9};
bool[] used  = {false, false, false, false, false};
int   keyValue;

while (<We have a new keyvalue to try>) {
    keyValue = <new value>;
    int foundValue = 0;
    int foundKey = 0;
    Foreach ( int x = 0; x < keys.length; x++ ){
        if ( keys[x] <= keyValue &&
             keys[x] >= foundKey &&
             !used[x])
        {
            foundKey = keys[x];
            if(values[x] > foundValue) {
                foundValue = values[x];
                used[x] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make the above more elegant, you could do the following:

- Pair the keys and values together
- Sort the key/value pairs in descending order by key
- In the search loop, you can skip to the next iteration as soon as a key matches
- You could also perform a check that at least one entry in the `used[]` array remains `false`, since if all are `true`, then the algorithm can be halted at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would work, but what I ended up doing was looping through the array, finding the matching index, do whatever I need to with the value, and then removing the element in the array at that index, and encased the whole block in a `while keys.size() > 0`.